# working directory of a notebook run by startup script is not its real path, but '/'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, startupscript, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, papermill

I have a notebook instance with a startup script that uses papermill to execute a notebook.
The problem is that the working directory is '/' and not the path of the file. How do I get the path of the file so I can set it as the working directory?

This is how I update my script:

```
gcloud... --metadata startup-script="/opt/conda/bin/papermill /home/jupyter/some_dir/mynotebook.ipynb /home/jupyter/some_dir/out1.ipynb"
```

Comment: normally you want to use full paths for referencing files. Can you share the example command ? Example: papermill gs://my-bucket/test.ipynb /tmp/test.ipynb

Comment: Can you share the startup script/command that you are executing?

Comment: @gogasca ... --metadata startup-script="/opt/conda/bin/papermill /home/jupyter/some_dir/mynotebook.ipynb /home/jupyter/some_dir/out1.ipynb". So the notebook is run, but when it's run, its working directory is '/'.

Comment: @DavicC shared it in the post

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, where is the input notebook? and where do you want the output notebook to be? what error do you get? Anyways check this post with a script (notebook_executor.sh) I wrote a while back: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-jupyter-on-a-google-cloud-vm-5ba1b473f4c2

Comment: @gogasca my script is executed, but its working directory is '/' and I want it to be the notebook's path (/home/jupyter/some_dir) in my case.

Comment: You can do a "cd" first then run papermill? I assume you need this because your notebook has dependencies?

Comment: @gogasca The script reads files from some directories with relative paths. So it will be like "cd /home/jupyter/some_dir \n /opt/conda..."? the '\n' is how I separate the commands inside the script?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly

Comment: @gogasca they show examples that can't be done. How can you write code in different lines in a cmd terminal...

Comment: The [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) given by @gogasca already shows code in different lines. In the reference you can see --metadata startup-script="your code here; your code at the next line" using ";" acts as new line.